# ggplot2 asking for a non-existent aesthetic in geom_errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I actually found the answer to be my problem but I was wondering whether this is a bug or not.

Suppose I have this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
first <-
mtcars %>%
  group_by(vs) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(mpg),
            lower_ci = mean(mpg) - 2 * sd(mpg),
            upper_ci = mean(mpg) + 2 * sd(mpg))
```

I can make a layered plot like this:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(vs))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mpg), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(data = first, aes(y = mean), colour = "red") +
  geom_errorbar(data = first, aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci))
```

Great, no problem. Let's recreate the plot step by step.

```
graph <- ggplot()
graph <- graph + geom_point(alpha = 0.2)
graph <- graph %+% mtcars + aes(x = as.factor(vs), y = mpg)
graph <- graph + geom_point(data = first, aes(x = as.factor(vs), y = mean, colour = "red"))
```

At this point I only have to overlay the error bars which need the `x`, `ymin` and `ymax` `aes`thethics. However, the `graph` object has a predefined `y` in the structure of the object. For some reason, if I add this:

```
graph + geom_errorbar(data = first,
                               aes(x = as.factor(vs), ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci))
```

which I would think is the right way, it throws an error about the length of the `aes`thetic. Naturally, the `first` data frame has the correct lengths, so I figured it should be passing the `y` `aes`thetic from the global options.

If I add this:

```
graph + geom_errorbar(data = first,
                               aes(x = as.factor(vs), y = NULL, ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci))
```

It fixes it and as expected throws the `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: y`.

I would assume that the global options of the object would recognize that `geom_errorbar` doesn't require a `y` `aes`thetic.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

No. You identified the issue correctly; you are just assuming there is something else. It's a small bug that probably isn't worth fixing.

> I would assume that the global options of the object would recognize that `geom_errorbar` doesn't require a y aesthetic.

Aesthetics are inherited by default (you can avoid the error by setting `inherit.aes = FALSE`)), and they are immediately checked against the available data. If an inherited mapped column isn't available because it isn't in the data frame for the layer, an error is thrown.

Here's another example. It's not really different from the one in your question, but it uses more common `geom`s and is a little simpler:

```
df1 = data.frame(x1 = 1:2, y1 = 3:4, ty = 'a')
df2 = data.frame(x2 = 1, y2 = 5)

ggplot(df1, aes(x1, y1, linetype = ty)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = x2, y = y2))
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ty' not found
```

Even though `geom_point` doesn't take a `linetype` aesthetic, because there isn't a data column in `df2` named `ty`, we get an error. As below, the easy fix is to set `inherit.aes = FALSE`:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x1, y1, lintype = ty)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = x2, y = y2), inherit.aes = FALSE)
## works
```

Comment: In both your code and the @cimentadaj's  code you specify a new data source in the second aes().  So the references in the geom_ are to the new data set.  Assuming a priori that matching variable names in two separate data frames represent the same variables seems like a recipe for problems.   I don't think it's a bug at all to default to not making that assumption.

Comment: I'm not sure I see your point. I used data similar to the data in the question - two data frames with a shared column name indicating the same variable. If one does have the same variable in different data frames (as OP seems to), I think using the same column name is probably a good idea.

Comment: I think this is not the forum you're looking for if you want to discuss design decisions in `ggplot2`. From a software perspective, the implementation makes sense to me because each layer knows what data to look at, but doesn't need to worry about what data other layers are looking at. The point layer shouldn't change behavior depending on whether the line layer is referencing the same data frame or not.